# Hide class of a member which is only used in private associations?

Tags: delphi, oop

Given following example, is there any way to make the class `TPrivateUseOnly` private resp. move it to the `implementation` section? Imho, it is not possible. But I am not sure if I have missed some OOP feature of the new generation of Delphi language.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TPrivateUseOnly = class(TObject)
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FXYZ: TPrivateUseOnly;
  public
    ...
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: I would put that *private class* into a separate unit, which would not be intended for use for *public* (which is still hard to prevent), but it's just a *poor* workaround for what you're asking...

Comment: Hide the class from access, or from the eyes of the reader? If the former, make it a private nested class, as suggested. If the latter, make it an interface and implement that in a unit you don't distribute as source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a nested class. If you put this class in the strict private section then it will not be available to any other units:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  strict private
    type
      TPrivateUseOnly = class(TObject)
        test: boolean;
      end;
  strict private
    FXYZ: TPrivateUseOnly;
  public
    ...
  end;
```

If I then try and access the private class in another unit I get the following error:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(28): E2361 Cannot access private symbol TMyClass.TPrivateUseOnly
```

When you refer to the nested class inside TMyClass you access it with `TPrivateUseOnly`. If you need to access it inside of the unit then it would need to be `private` and you would access it with `TMyClass.TPrivateUseOnly`.

Comment: [`This is documented`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Nested_Type_Declarations).

Comment: @TLama I thought I remembered seeing it. Not something I like to do but it should do what the question asks. The internal class is private, not so?

Comment: It depends. You can make it `public` and use it as `TMyClass.TPublicInnerClass`. But I don't see any benefit of doing so. Btw. you should repeat `strict private` instead of `var` if you want to conform the `FXYZ` field with the original in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! I didn't yet know about nested classes, I just knew them from Java. But why is `strict private var` different than repeating `strict private` for types and members? Is the visibility really different?

Comment: `var` and `strict private` are completely different things. They cannot be compared. The former introduces a list of variables. The latter specifies the visibility of the declarations that follow.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in this comment stream it reads as though `var` and `strict private` are alternatives, either or.